# CSS Footer not auto moving down

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS Code for my website:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body, #wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Calibri;
}
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto -580px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
    border:4px solid #000000;
}

.push {
    height: 580px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

/* header stuff */
#header-topbar {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    /* padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; */
    background-color:#666666;
}
#header-topbar2 {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    /* padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; */
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
#phone-tel {
    float:right;
    margin-right:16%;
    margin-top:5px;
    font-size:20px;
}
#logo {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    margin-left:15%;
    margin-top:15px;
}

/* main body/content */
#body-content {
    padding-bottom:200px;
    width:80%;
    margin:120px auto 0 auto;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border:solid 1px #a79494;
    border-top:solid 4px #a2cd3a;
}

/* homepage-boxes */
#homepagebox {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
#homepagebox .column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
#homepagebox .column div {
    margin: 5px;
    min-height: 350px;
    background: #eeeeee;
}

/* FOOTER */
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:580px;
    border-top:4px solid #666666;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
#footer-inner {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    height:inherit;
}
#footerTop {
    width:100%;
    height:480px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-bottom:2px #000000 solid;
}
#footerTopLeft {
    width:30%;
    height:420px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:0 15px 10px 15px;
    border-right:1px solid #000000;
}
#footerTopMid {
    width:30%;
    height:420px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:0 15px 10px 15px;
    border-right:1px solid #000000;
}
#footerTopRight {
    width:30%;
    height:420px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    padding:0 15px 10px 15px;
}

#enquiryForm                    { clear:both; padding:8px 40px 0 0;  }
.enquiryField                   { clear:both; padding:5px 0; }
.enquiryField label             { clear:none; float:left; }
.enquiryField input             { clear:none; font-family:Calibri; float:right; padding:3px; width:189px; }
.enquiryField textarea          { clear:none; float:right; font-family:Calibri; padding:5px; width:189px; }

.enquiryError                   { clear:both; color:#fff; font-family:Calibri; }
#enquirySent                    { color:#fff; font-family:Calibri; }
```

the footer displays at the bottom of the page but if the main page content is too long the footer doesnt move down at all. the content just displays over the footer.

for example, in my HTML I have 4 divs aligned next to each other and they are displaying over the footer

i have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rwqjH/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear your floating elements, add the below line before `<div class="push"></div>`

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rwqjH/1/)

> Note: I've not fixed your footer alignments, they are pretty messed
>   up, I would suggest you to learn CSS positioning

Comment: yes you are missing clearing your floats, but even beyond that i think you should try to redo your css from scratch as it's quite messy in there for something that should be quite simple. You can also google "micro clearfix" that should make using floats alot easier for you. I'd also avoid using !important ..it has its uses, but has no reason to be anywhere in your css in 99.9% of all cases. This is asking for trouble.

Comment: Agreed with the above comment

Answer (score 0):

try adding `overflow:auto;` to #wrap. When you float elements they get removed from the layout and #wrap no longer resizes to fit them by default.